# Using variable in $_FILES['file']['name']

Tags: php, image, file, post

Is there any way to use a variable in the actual `$_FILES['file']` section? I am uploading multiple images that are not always uploaded.  For example, I can update a potential of 1-4 images but want to be able to just upload `#3` or `#4` in an instance.  Code is like this:

```
if($selectedimages != ''){
    foreach ($selectedimages as $i){

        $imagename = $productid."-".$i;
        $imageid = "image_loc-".$imagename;
        if($_FILES['$imageid']['name']!=''){
```

but it will not register the variable in the file for name, is there anyway to do this?

the other variables are definitely valid as I already checked them, the function is just dying at this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: `if($_FILES[$imageid]['name']!=''){` -- just don't use quotes and it won't be treated as a literal.

Comment: Double quotes would technically also work (though no quotes makes more sense) - it's only single quotes that interpret dollar signs as literal characters.

Comment: @Brilliand of course, but that's generally only useful when embedding variables as part of a larger string which also contains literals.